# Recursive validation using annotations and IValidatableObject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to validate nested objects (not models in the MVC senss) using annotations and some custom code.

I found the following post useful

[Using Data Annotations Validation Manually and Object Graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938877/using-data-annotations-validation-manually-and-object-graphs)

As suggested in an answer, I've created an extra routine in the container class to validate the nested object. Here's my modified test code

```
public class Customer : IValidatableObject
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Details = new CustomerDetails();
    }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public CustomerDetails Details
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(this.Details, validationContext.ServiceContainer, validationContext.Items);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(this.Details, context, results);
        return results;
    }
}
```

However I have problems getting *all* the validation errors, even when calling TryValidateObject with validateAllProperties set to true.

```
        var context = new ValidationContext(cs, null, null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(cs, context, results,true);
```

If there are any errors in the container, only these will show. Only when there are no errors in the container object, errors in the nested object will show. I suspect it has something to do with the Validate rouine returning a full list, and not being able to add to an (existing) list from the container(?)

Are there any modifications I can make to routine to get all errors to show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3400627/724944

So, there is an error in your class' atributes, and therefore Validate method doesn't get called.
I suggest using [CustomValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.aspx) like this:

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(Customer), "ValidateRelatedObject")]
public CustomerDetails Details
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public static ValidationResult ValidateRelatedObject(object value, ValidationContext context)
{
    var context = new ValidationContext(value, validationContext.ServiceContainer, validationContext.Items);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    Validator.TryValidateObject(value, context, results);

    // TODO: Wrap or parse multiple ValidationResult's into one ValidationResult

    return result;

}
```

Comment: Ok, if I understand you correctly, "validateAllProperties" will only affect annotated properties, not a separate Validate routine? But I did try to implement your routine, but I have problems with what you left as TODO. As ValidateRelatedObject returns a single ValidationResult, (for a single annotated property), how can I have it push a potential list of errors (from the nested object) into the list of potential errors from the container objects? The original example seemed more promising in this regard as it returned a list. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: In my project I simply enumerate all ValidationResult's and Merge errors into one string, separated by new line. Later, when I need to use it, I just split the error into multiple lines. You might also consider creating a class like MultiValidationResult which will store actual ValidationResult's and expose concatenated error.