# How do I do Sub Object Custom Validation mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an object (header) that has a list of sub-ojects (details) that I want to do custom validation on prior to accepting data.  I've tried ModelState.IsValid and TryValidateModel, but it doesn't seem to fire the Validate method on the sub-objects (only the header object).

So on submission I see the validation fire for the header, but not the sub-ojects.  Then if I do a TryValidateModel I again see (breakpoint) the validation method get called on the header, but not on the sub-objects.

The annotated validation (must be number, etc...) seems to be working on the sub-objects, just not the custom logic added via the IValidatableObject interface.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TryValidateObject didn't appear to fire custom validation, only data annotations?  I went down the path of adding validation of the details to the header validation by doing the following:

```
foreach (var detail in this.Details)
{
   var validationResults = detail.Validate(validationContext);
   foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
   {
      yield return validationResult;
   }
}
```

This worked in terms of validation, but the UI didn't display the error messages.  Even though I have ValidationMessagesFor on the UI.

Validation not working solved here: [MVC3 Master-Details Validation not Displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791361/mvc3-master-details-validation-not-displaying)

Answer (score 1):

I make an attribute ( [ValidateObject] ) and it will validate the attribute you put on your class, like you would think it suppose to do.

```
public class Personne
{
    [ValidateObject]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    //[...]
}
```

(Address is a custom class.)

It can be used for validating:

- Object properties on a model. (like above)
- Collection of sub object.

  ```
  [ValidateObject]
  public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
  ```
- It support multi level of dept, if "Address" had a propertie of type "ZipCode" with the attribute [ValidateObject] it would be validate tho.

Code:

```
public class ValidateObjectAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public ValidateObjectAttribute()
    {

    }
    private ValidationContext ValidationContext { get; set; }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        this.ValidationContext = validationContext;
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        try
        {
            var isIterable = this.IsIterable(value);
            if (isIterable)
            {
                int currentItemPosition = -1;
                foreach (var objectToValidate in value as IEnumerable<object>)
                {
                    currentItemPosition++;
                    var resultTemp = ValidationsForObject(objectToValidate, true, currentItemPosition);
                    if (resultTemp != null)
                        results.AddRange(resultTemp);

                }
                if (results.Count <= 0)
                    results = null;
            }
            else
                results = ValidationsForObject(value);

            if (results != null)
            {
                //Build a validation result 
                List<string> memberNames = new List<string>();
                results.ForEach(r => memberNames.AddRange(r.MemberNames));

                var compositeResultsReturn = new CompositeValidationResult($"Validation for {validationContext.DisplayName} failed!", memberNames.AsEnumerable());
                results.ForEach(r => compositeResultsReturn.AddResult(r));

                return compositeResultsReturn;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    private List<ValidationResult> ValidationsForObject (object objectToValidate, bool IsIterable = false, int position = -1)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var contextTemp = new ValidationContext(objectToValidate, null, null);
        var resultsForThisItem = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(objectToValidate, contextTemp, resultsForThisItem, true);
        if (isValid)
            return null;

        foreach (var validationResult in resultsForThisItem)
        {
            List<string> propNames = new List<string>();// add prefix to properties
            foreach (var nameOfProp in validationResult.MemberNames)
            {
                if (IsIterable)
                    propNames.Add($"{this.ValidationContext.MemberName}[{position}].{nameOfProp}");
                else
                    propNames.Add($"{this.ValidationContext.MemberName}.{nameOfProp}");
            }
            var customFormatValidation = new ValidationResult(validationResult.ErrorMessage, propNames);
            results.Add(customFormatValidation);
        }       

        return results;
    }


    private bool IsIterable(object value)
    {
        ////COULD WRITE THIS, but its complicated to debug...
        //if (value.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(
        //i => i.IsGenericType &&
        //i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
        //{
        //    // foreach...
        //}
        Type valueType = value.GetType();
        var interfaces = valueType.GetInterfaces();
        bool isIterable = false;
        foreach (var i in interfaces)
        {
            var isGeneric = i.IsGenericType;
            bool isEnumerable = i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>);
            isIterable = isGeneric && isEnumerable;
            if (isIterable)
                break;
        }
        return isIterable;
    }
}

public class CompositeValidationResult : ValidationResult
{
    private readonly List<ValidationResult> _results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Results
    {
        get
        {
            return _results;
        }
    }

    public CompositeValidationResult(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage)
    {
    }

    public CompositeValidationResult(string errorMessage, IEnumerable<string> memberNames) : base(errorMessage, memberNames)
    {
    }

    protected CompositeValidationResult(ValidationResult validationResult) : base(validationResult)
    {
    }

    public void AddResult(ValidationResult validationResult)
    {
        _results.Add(validationResult);
    }
}
```

This will work if you model is correctly binded :)

You might want to add the required attribute, making sure the the object is not null itself.

```
[Required]
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you root object has errors preventing child validation.
See [Recursive validation using annotations and IValidatableObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548482/recursive-validation-using-annotations-and-ivalidatableobject)
This URL mentions that scenario and also code to force validation on the child from the root

As per the posting triggering off the validation from the root object

```
  public IEnumerable Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(this.Details, validationContext.ServiceContainer, validationContext.Items);
        var results = new List();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(this.Details, context, results);
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the root object has errors (non-expected and ModelState.IsValid = true)

Comment: Try the other suggestion of ensuring the root validates the child in your Validate method as shown in that post or use the attribute based approach.